# Scatterplot update: same number of data points, but new data points

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

Apologies in advance that my question does not include code, but rather is a high level question on D3 and how to build my app correctly. I will attempt to make my question as clear and concise as possible:

I am building a React / D3 app that creates a scatter graph of NBA team logos, that allows users to click buttons to choose variables for the X and Y axis. The user can also filter the graph to include only certain teams (those in a particular division of the NBA).

Here is a quick demo gif of the app that features the main problem I am having:

[image]
.

.
.
.
and [here](http://ec2-54-158-72-16.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/nba/teamstats) is the link to my app for anyone interested.

### What is working correctly

When I change the X or Y axis button (2nd half of the gif), the team logos correctly slide to their new locations.

### What is working incorrectly

When I change the division (1st half of gif), it changes the 5 team logos that are showing, which is correct. However, the animation (which I show a few times in the gif) is incorrect. The old logos should simply disappear in place, and the new logos should simply appear in place. Instead, the logos change and slide.

I understand why the animation is doing this - D3 sees 5 data points before the update, and 5 data points after the update, but doesn't distinguish that my points are unique (different team logos). Since the updated data points have new (x,y) locations (different stats for each team), it simply animates the old logos to the locations of the new logos.

### My proposed fix

I think the structure of my app is holding be back with regards to fixing this. Currently, I have a container component that loads the data, filters the teams (based on the division selected), and then passes the filtered data (an array of objects with the team stats) into a graph component that creates the logo scatter graph.

If, on the other hand, I pass the full object (of all 30 teams) to the graph component, then **could I fix this problem** by simply having D3 change the "fill" of the markers to transparent when they are filtered out? This way, there are always 30 logos being plotted, although 25 would be invisible, and the logos displaying should animate correctly.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Edit: please let me know if the post is unclear in any way and I will try to clarify. I try to avoid posting Qs without code, but this is a fairly high level Q that focuses on how the D3 general update pattern works, and how I can build a graph with a specific animation that works within the general update pattern framework.

Edit2: The radio buttons are built in the **container component** here. Using my API to grab the data from my database, and then using these radio buttons to filter the data, are all done in the container component. I am considering bringing these radio buttons into the graph component and building them with D3. I think I may have to.

Edit3: Should have shared earlier, here is the D3 code that makes these markers:

```
const update = svg.select('g.points')
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(graphData);

// Second exit and remove
update.exit().remove();

// Third Update
update
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${(xScale(+d[xColname]) - logoRadius)}, ${(yScale(+d[yColname]) - logoRadius)})`)
        .attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0)
        .attr("height", logoRadius)
        .attr("width", logoRadius)
        .attr("fill", d => `url(#teamlogo-${d.teamAbbrev})`)
        .attr("opacity", 0.95);

// And Fourth transition
update
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .delay((d, i) => i * 15)
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${(xScale(+d[xColname]) - logoRadius)}, ${(yScale(+d[yColname]) - logoRadius)})`)
        .attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0)
        .attr("height", logoRadius)
        .attr("width", logoRadius)
        .attr("fill", d => `url(#teamlogo-${d.teamAbbrev})`)
        .attr("opacity", 0.95);
```

Comment: *"The old logos should simply disappear in place, and the new logos should simply appear in place"*. This can be easily achieved with exit and enter selections. So, even if the number of data points is the same, you have to have an enter/update/exit selection: the teams are **different**.

Comment: I do have an enter / update / exit selection - i will edit the post with that code and then comment on it

Comment: I'm not very strong wrt the general update pattern, so there's probably other issues in the code as well. For now I just want to focus on having both of these (seemingly separate) animations work.

Comment: the teams are different, but doesn't the D3 general update pattern just look for the number of objects in the data array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here seems to be just the lack of a key function during the data join.

You asked in the [comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352540/d3-scatterplot-update-same-number-of-data-points-but-new-data-points#comment89677934_51352540):

> Doesn't the D3 general update pattern just look for the number of objects in the data array?

If you set up a key function the answer is **no**. The thing is that...

> If a key function is not specified, then the first datum in data is assigned to the first selected element, the second datum to the second selected element, and so on. A key function may be specified to control which datum is assigned to which element, replacing the default join-by-index, by computing a string identifier for each datum and element. ([source](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data))

So, if you don't set up a key function, because you have always just 5 teams you don't effectively have working enter and exit selections when you change the division, but just an update one: as you're binding the data by their order, D3 thinks that Chicago Bulls and Atlanta Hawks are the same team.

**Solution**: set up a key function.

It can be simple as using the team abbreviation (supposing they are **unique**):

```
const update = svg.select('g.points')
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(graphData, function(d){
        return d.teamAbbrv;
    });
```

---

PS: Just a question not related to your problem: why are you appending rects here? Since you have `logoRadius`, doesn't appending circles seem more natural? On top of that, the data representation would be more accurate, since the center of the circle, regardless its size, is at the correct datum coordinate. That's not the case with a rectangle, in which the coordinates (`x`, `y`) represent its top left corner.

Comment: thank you, your answers are always helpful. 

I had the logos as circles originally, which it why their size is dictated by `logoRadius`, but I recently changed to rects since (i think) the logos look better. The defs / patterns have a height and width, and due to logo shapes, there is some cutoff with circles.

I will have to update the translate() to account for the locations with rects, which is something i hadn't considered before.

Comment: Yes, remember to translate the rectangles half the `logoRadius` length up and left.